# Assetic dump and moving the symfony project to a new directory

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, assetic

I am working on a first time symfony project (with Mopa Bootstrap) in a subdirectory on a development server (/var/www/www.example1.com). The subdirectory is called www.example1.com and is loaded this way: http://devserver.myname.com/www.example1.com.

When I do

```
php app/console assetic:dump --force --watch
```

All is working well.

Now I copied the whole project to a new subdirectory: www.example2.com

When I execute the assetic:dump command from this new directory the result shows that the css and js files are compiling into the old directory www.example1.com. How can I change this?

Comment: Try app/console cache:clear

Comment: Did that already, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that app/console cache:clear does not work in this case because not all cache files where deleted. Removing the cache by hand did:

```
sudo rm -rf -- app/cache/prod app/cache/dev
```

After removing the cache file by hand app/console assetic:dump --force --watch compiles the files to the right directory.